# Inheritance, why do two constructors get called for base class, C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to do an assignment in my book but I do not understand the output. When the main code in the program is run the output is:

B::B(3)

B::B() //why is this outputted

B::B(-3)

D::D(3)

It gets this from calling `B::B(int n) {}` first and then `B::B() {}` followed by the the next two lines which I get. So the program called the first one since it is declared as the constructor the class A in the function and it has to assign values, what I dont get is output line 2, why is `B::B() {}` even called? it gets called as a constructor but shouldnt just the constructor with parameters get called?

```
class B {
public:
    B(); //why is this  called?
    B(int n);
};

// Definitions of B
B::B() { 
    cout << "B::B()\n";
}
B::B(int n) {
    cout << "B::B(" << n << ")\n";
}

class D : public B {
public:
    D();
    D(int n);
private:
    B b;
};

// Definitions of D
D::D() {
    cout << "D::D()\n";
}
D::D(int n) : B(n) {
    b = B(-n);
    cout << "D::D("<< n <<")\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    D d(3);
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First the base class constructor is called: `B::B(3)`.
Then the constructor for the `b` field is called: `B::B()`.
Then the derived constructor body is executed (*after* all fields are constructed).
`D`'s constructor first constructs another `B` on the line `b = B(-n);` (so `B::B(-3)` is printed), then prints `D::D(3)`.

Comment: But why is the the constructor for the b field called though? isnt B::B(3) the constructor for the b field?

Comment: That's the constructor for the base class. A derived class implicitly contains a base class object. Your `B b;` is superfluous if you need only one `B`.

Comment: @user2076774 No, the `b` field is a completely normal field that has nothing to do with the base class (except that it coincidentally has the same type).

Answer (score 0):

Your class `D` contains two objects of type `B`.

1. the implicit `B` from inheritance
2. the explicit `B` member named `b`

You could rewrite the constructor

```
D::D(int n) : B(n)
{
    b = B(-n);
    cout << "D::D("<< n <<")\n";
}
```

like

```
D::D(int n) : B(n), b()
{
    b = B(-n);
    cout << "D::D("<< n <<")\n";
}
```

where it is apparent where the `B::B()` comes from. Thus your output is easily explained:

```
B::B(3) // base constructor of `D`
B::B() // default construction of `b` member
B::B(-3) // explicit construction inside D::D(int)
D::D(3) // D::D(int)
```

If you write

```
D::D(int n) : B(n), b(-n)
{
    cout << "D::D("<< n <<")\n";
}
```

instead, there is only

```
B::B(3)
B::B(-3)
D::D(3)
```

left.

Addressing the comment:

Imagine `D` to look like:

```
class D : public B
{
public:
  D(int);
};
```

with the constructor definition

```
D::D(int v) { std::cout << "foo with " << v; }
```

then, the code

```
D d(3);
```

prints

```
B::B()
foo with 3
```

and it is perfectly valid as long as `B` is default constructible.

If `B` would lack a default constructor you'd get a compiler error and you'd want to rewrite the definition of `D` to

```
D::D(int v) : B(3) { std::cout << "foo with " << v; }
```

Every direct base class or member that is *not* part of the constructors initializer list is default constructed (in case of a class type) or left uninitialized in case of a fundamental type.

Comment: Okay so whenever you have a derived class calling a constructor, does it always have to have a constructor for the Base class? Say that D::D(int n) : B(n) {} was just D::D(int n) {} and printed out a string instead of calling an object, would an error occur since 'b' data field object is not included?

Comment: So even if I don't have an object of class b instantiated in my main code the default constructor for class B is run?

Comment: @user2076774: Did you read my last sentence? The default constructor is only called if you leave a member or base type from the initializer list.

Comment: Sorry the concept is just weird for me. In the second example that you wrote for the edit, if b is a private variable, although it isn't called in D::D(int v) { std::cout << "foo with " << v; } it is still default constructed?

Comment: @user2076774 Is `b` initialized in `D::D(int v) { std::cout << "foo with " << v; }` explicitly? .... No, therefore it is initialized implicitly (which is default construction).

Comment: in the above example, why would a private variable 'b' that is not explicitly called in a function be constructed? why not wait until it is explicitily called to construct it?

Comment: @user2076774: If you create an instance of a class you also create an instance of every member variable and base class. The member `b` is part of `D` and every instance has a constructed `b` inside.